# How can I change parent's form webControl source on child form?

Tags: c#, awesomium

I'm using a webControl (awesomium) on my Form1.

When application starts (form1) it shows a second form (Form2).

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Then I execute a method of form2 and it closes automatically.

Well.. I'm stucked here! I want to set Form1 webControl1.Source = new Uri("http://www.example.com/"); when Form2 is closing..

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Expose webcontrol as property of Form1

   public WebControl MyWebControl
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
2. In form 2 you can access it as

   ```
   Form1 f1= new Form1();
   f1.MyWebControl.xyz =pqr;
   ```